# Regex: How to match whole words withonly a single dash in it not more than 1 dash?

Tags: regex

I have these words

```
verification-asdflkaasidmf
verification-sadfim-aisdmfim
```

I'd like to match the first `verification-asdflkaasidmf` but not the second one (which has 2 dashes)

Comment: You may use; `/^\w+-\w+$/`

Comment: (verification-.*?\n)

Comment: @anubhava that works perfectly, thanks! I feel that is very readable as well. If you put write an answer I can mark is as complete since you were the first to respond?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```
/^\w+-\w+$/
```

This regex matches a word at the start followed by hyphen followed by another word in the end.

```js
let arr = ['verification-asdflkaasidmf',
'verification-sadfim-aisdmfim'
];

let regex = /^\w+-\w+$/;

for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i], regex.test(arr[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be:

```
^[^-]*\-[^-]*$
```

Which consists of the following:

```
^      begining of the string
[^-]*  all characters except - zero or more times
\-     literal -
[^-]*  all characters except - zero or more times
$      end of the string
```